# How to change the CSS class of each label based on the textContent value

Tags: javascript, html, css, jinja2

I have an HTML template with `jinja` tags that create labels dynamically from a list of in a JSON object. The loop that creates that content is as follow.

```
<div class="card mb-0">
    {% for turn in response %}
        <div class="card-header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse{{turn['turn_id']}}" href="#">
            <a class="card-title"> {{turn['author_name']}} {{turn['date_time']}} </a>
            </div>
                  <div id="collapse{{turn['turn_id']}}" class="card-body collapse in" >
                       <ul>
                            {% for sent in turn['list_of_sentences'] %}
                                <li>{{sent['text']}}</li>
                                {% for tag in sent['tags'] %}
                                    <label><span class="badge" id="{{tag}}">{{ tag }}</span></label>
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endfor %}
                       </ul>
                  </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I have a javascript function that changes the css class based on the label ID because I assigned the label's textContent to the ID.

```
$(window).on('load', change_label_css );

function change_label_css(){
    console.log("Changing CSS classes");
    if (document.getElementById("OT").textContent === "OT"){
        console.log(document.getElementById("OT").textContent);
        document.getElementById("OT").className = "badge badge-warning";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("RES").textContent === "RES"){
        console.log(document.getElementById("RES").textContent);
        document.getElementById("RES").className = "badge badge-success";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("DES").textContent === "DES"){
        console.log(document.getElementById("DES").textContent);
        document.getElementById("DES").className = "badge badge-light";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("CW").textContent === "CW"){
        console.log(document.getElementById("CW").textContent);
        document.getElementById("CW").className = "badge badge-info";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("Org").textContent === "Org"){
        console.log(document.getElementById("Org").textContent);
        document.getElementById("Org").className = "badge badge-primary";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("QT").textContent === "QT"){
        console.log(document.getElementById("QT").textContent);
        document.getElementById("QT").className = "badge badge-primary";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("URL").textContent === "URL"){
        console.log(document.getElementById("URL").textContent);
        document.getElementById("URL").className = "badge badge-secondary";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById("C").textContent === "C"){
        console.log(document.getElementById("C").textContent);
        document.getElementById("C").className = "badge badge-dark";
    }
    console.log("End of changing CSS classes");
}
```

I don't think this is the right logic since I have labels with different IDs and similar IDs.

I would like a suggestion on how to travel through each label and change the CSS class based on the textContent.

Comment: maybe looking through your labels via https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll would avoid ids needs (ids cannot be used twice in a document :( )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an object containing all the labels and their corresponding classes:

```
const labelClassMap = {
    "OT": "badge badge-warning",
    "RES": "badge badge-success"
    ...
}
```

Then iterate over all of the relevant labels, so all of the labels whose classes have to be set, and set their class values by comparing the textContent against the map you have just created.

```
for(let label of document.querySelectorAll("label" /*You may adjust the selector here*/)){
   label.classList.add(...labelClassMap[label.textContent].split(" "))
}
```

Comment: Could someone explain what `...` inside the parenthesis

Comment: ``...`` spreads the array returned by ``split``, since ``classList.add`` requires a list of class names and not one string of classes seperated by spaces.